# How to properly open image from remote URL with PHP5+Imagick?

Tags: php, url, imagemagick, imagick

I tried this code:

```
$image = new Imagick();
$f = fopen('http://www.url.com/image.jpg', 'rb');
$image = readImageFile($f);
```

but it doesn't work.
Also, I believe it's not the best way to do it and I want the code to include best practices (now matter how ridiculous it sounds).
On the same server, this code, using GD library, works just fine.

```
 $im = imagecreatefromjpeg('http://www.url.com/image.jpg');
```

Did I miss something in Imagick manual?

Comment: are you getting an error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try replacing:

```
$image = readImageFile($f)
```

with

```
$image->readImageFile($f);
```

Comment: Oh God, what a typo! Of course you're right but even if it's written correctly it still doesn't work.